# Preventing Eclipse product from starting if execution environment is not satisfied

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Execution environment of my plugins is set to Java 7, if I start with Java 6 Eclipse starts up in kind of stripped down version. Can I alert user that he is running unsupported JRE? Perhaps similar message when starting Eclipse without any JRE installed. I know, product release notes, but who reads those, right?

Comment: Is this a RCP or is it plugins for a standard Eclipse?

Comment: @greg-449 Standard Eclipse with plugins/features that make up the product.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a plugin which uses the `org.eclipse.ui.startup` extension point to run early on in the Eclipse startup. The plugin could check that the JRE matches you requires and display an error dialog.

Obviously this plugin would not depend on Java 7.

Comment: I tried it as I use this extension in other areas. However, earlyStartup() is called too late, as JavaDoc says: "Will be called in a separate thread after the workbench initializes." I will explain my solution in separate answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating plugin, let's call it startup, that has execution environments from 1.2 to 1.6. Then in my product I added this plugin to configuration with start level 1. Finally, in startup's Activator I have:

```
public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    super.start(context);
    if(!SystemUtils.isJavaVersionAtLeast(JavaVersion.JAVA_1_7)){
        MessageDialog.openInformation(new Shell(), "Unsupported JRE", "Message to user");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    plugin = this;
}
```

[SystemUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/SystemUtils.html#isJavaVersionAtLeast%28org.apache.commons.lang3.JavaVersion%29) is a utility class from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) project that I use here to check for valid JRE version.

So the idea here is that when this plugin executes under these various supported JRE versions, it will check for validity of JRE installed and inform user if their JRE is wrong.